# Arithmetic Progression (AP) - In the question, it will entail no sequence numbers, it will be based on two terms. The 8th Term and the 16th Term

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

If the 8th term of an AP is 36 and the 16th term is 68

Find: 
a) the first term.
b) the common difference.
c) The 20th term.

Comment: Did you try even one attempt to solve it besides the writing to SE?

Comment: Hint: how many gaps are there between 8th and 16th term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$8^{th} term=a_1+7d=36\\16^{th} term=a_1+15d=68$$
It follows $$d=\frac{68-36}{8}=4$$ Hence
$$a_1=36-7\cdot 4=8\\a_{20}=a_{16}+4\cdot4=68+16=84$$